# Why does BigQueryTimestamp not support nanosecond precision but seems to be able to?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I made a test query run from node.js that does a simple `SELECT` from a BigQuery table in which one of the rows is in `BigQueryTimestamp` format.

As we know, this format supports up to microsecond precision and nothing more. I was confused when I read the value of the timestamp it had returned and saw that it had placeholder 0 values for nanosecond precision:

```bash
BigQueryTimestamp { value: '2023-08-09T11:57:19.099651000Z' }
                                                123456789 → 1e-9s → nano
```

Why does BigQuery apparently have the ability to support nanosecond precision but does not allow it?

Comment: I have no technical reason, only Google can answer you on that. But I guess that it for having the same format before and after the nano feature support. In the documentation, only the micro second was printed in the sample. You can see the recent under the hood evolution. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions